# Importing CSV with Polygon data in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, geometry, polygon

I'm trying to import a CSV using phpMyAdmin. This is what my CSV looks like:

```
1,1,1,'POLYGON ((879350.00000000012 4542950.0,882236.75134594808 4547950.0,888010.25403784448 4547950.0,890897.00538379245 4542950.0,888010.25403784448 4537950.0,882236.75134594808 4537950.0,879350.00000000012 4542950.0))','POINT (885123.50269189617 4542950.0)'
2,1,2,'POLYGON ((879350.00000000012 4552950.0,882236.75134594808 4557950.0,888010.25403784448 4557950.0,890897.00538379245 4552950.0,888010.25403784448 4547950.0,882236.75134594808 4547950.0,879350.00000000012 4552950.0))','POINT (885123.50269189617 4552950.0)'
3,1,3,'POLYGON ((879350.00000000012 4562950.0,882236.75134594808 4567950.0,888010.25403784448 4567950.0,890897.00538379245 4562950.0,888010.25403784448 4557950.0,882236.75134594808 4557950.0,879350.00000000012 4562950.0))','POINT (885123.50269189617 4562950.0)'
```

My column names and types are as follows:

```
CellId      int(11),
Type        int(1),
Name        varchar(255),
Geometry    polygon,
Centroid    point
```

No matter what I try I always seem to get the error

```
'Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1' or 'Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field'
```

What can I change to either the CSV or the import settings in phpMyAdmin to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't import geometry type easily. I'd suggest creating temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmptbl` (
  `a` int(11),
  `b` int(11),
  `c` varchar(255),
  `d` text,
  `e` text   
)
```

Import csv into that table, then convert it into your table using

```
INSERT INTO mytable (CellId,Type,Name,Geometry,Centroid)
   SELECT a,b,c,GeomFromText(d),PointFromText(e) FROM tmptbl
```

Comment: very good idea,

i add 1 more varchar column and import data [data format = "POINT(10 100)"] into it first. then, use update [table name] set [point column] = GeomFromText([varchar column]).